# How to update the spark library in AWS EMR cluster 5.27

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I got a customized spark sql jars and I would like to update it on the existing EMR clusters.

I know the existing spark jars are installed in /usr/lib/spark of master node. My question is that do I only have to update this one in master node? or do I also have to update it on other nodes like core or task nodes?

Thank you.